# log4cplus use in android application

Tags: android, file, logcat, log4cplus

I have integreted the log4cplus in my android application. Because I am a newbie in android platform, i have some problems.

In win32 platform , the fileappender will put the log file in the exe directory ,but in the android virtual device , I can't find the log file.

In win32 project ,the consoleappender will output the log to the console ,but in the andriod application, the log didn't output in the logcat window, it's puzzled me a lot .

Can some one get into the same troble before? please help me.

Comment: Would it not make more sense to use log4j?

Comment: oh , this log library is very strong ,I think it should be support andriod .

Answer (score 0):

You can the android log api for sending log outputs.
[refer this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

Comment: if i use this ,i have to modify the code of log4cplus . I don't know how the other people use log4cplus in android ndk application.